# TeXshop and autocompletion

Tags: texshop, mac, auto-completion

I have a question on TeXshop and autocompletion. In an OSX text editor (Textedit for instance) when you start writing a word and hit the esc key the uppermost words in the list proposed for autocompletion are the ones most recently typed. 
In TeXshop the same operation yields and alphabetical list, something quite useless.

So, here is my question: is there a way to force TeXshop to use the OSX autocompletion i.e. to remember the recently typed words and propose them first when the esc key is hit?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Basil!

Comment: This is the behaviour I see with the latest release of TeXshop, downloaded today (reports version 3.23). As such, it's 'off topic' as either (a) it's not reproducible or (b) it's fixed by updating your TeXshop (you don't give a version).