# Autocomplete with recent words in Texshop

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

The most recent version 3.57 seems only supporting autocomplete with a general list of possible words instead of from the words that have been typed. It was asked in an early post [TeXshop and autocompletion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117560/texshop-and-autocompletion) but the issue remains.

So I wonder if words that have recently been typed in Texshop will appear at the top of the autocomplete list, so that they can be selected easily. I have searched Texshop help but did not see it.

Comment: It *is* supported; I tried typing `xyzzy` (that shouldn't be a known word) and it appears in the list upon typing `xy` and hitting ESC.

Comment: The linked post was closed because TeXShop *does* use the OSX autocomplete. So if you type a completely novel word it will appear in the list of potential words.

Comment: @AlanMunn By "recent words" I mean the words that have recently been typed in the document will appear at the top of the autocomplete list, so that they can be selected easily.

Answer (score 2):

Autocompletion with recent words *is* supported. In the picture I show what I see when typing `xy` and hitting the ESC key.

[image]

You can clearly see the word, along with other possible completions from some dictionary.

TeXShop version 3.58

Comment: I see you mean that a novel word will be added to the dictionary. But by "recent words" I mean the words that have recently been typed in the document will appear at the top of the autocomplete list, so that they can be selected easily.